# jmeter help - test around polling /w meta refresh

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jmeter

I am new to jmeter and am working on putting together a test plan.  The hurdle I've encountered is as follows:

First, a POST is made to processForm.aspx

Then, the user is redirected to pleaseWait.aspx

This page either redirects immediately to results.aspx OR loads, with a META REFRESH tag set to refresh in 5 seconds (and this step is repeated).

Now -- I can get this to execute by doing the following:

```
HTTP Sampler POST to processForm.aspx
  Assert Response contains "<something on pleaseWait.aspx>"
While LAST
  HTTP Sampler GET to pleaseWait.aspx
    Assert Response contains "<something on results.aspx>"
```

However -- I don't care for this method, because it results in failed assertions (even though things are working as expected).  I am sure there must be some other way to do this?  Anyone more familiar with JMeter than I?

UPDATE:

Got it going by using Regular Expression Extractor instead of Assertions.

1) Add a User Defined Variables section at Test Plan Root
2) Add a variable to it "LoginWait" and "false"

```
HTTP Sampler POST to processForm.aspx
  RegEx Extract Response Body contains "<something on pleaseWait.aspx>" into LoginWait
While ${LoginWait}
  HTTP Sampler GET to pleaseWait.aspx
    RegEx Extract Response Body contains "<something on pleaseWait.aspx>" into LoginWait
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using "follow redirects" on your HTTP Request.  It would eliminate the logic you need, and still get you to the page you're going.

Comment: I am using "follow redirects" already.  The hiccup is that doesn't follow a meta refresh, so the pleaseWait.aspx page becomes "the last stop on the redirect chain".  I am thinking perhaps I can get around the problem by using jmeter VARIABLES instead of (or with) Assertions -- is it possible to do something like:  HTTP Request to processForm.aspx -> if the result contains A then set variable X = A else if result contains B then set variable X = B ?  Then I could use this in the while loop instead of LAST

Comment: You can do your proposition, one of two ways.  For either, use a regex to scrape the results then a) Use the IF controller with UserDefinedVariables or b) use a beanshell pre-processor and write some simple java code to set your variables